# Linux (Ubuntu 9.04) permissions - how do I remove rws?

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, file-permissions

I have a directory that has rwxrwsr-x as its permissions and I need to set group to rwx. How can I do this on the command-line? I have root access.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`rwxrwsr-x` means that the set group ID is set. You can turn off set GID by doing this:

```
chmod g-s [name]
```

Comment: Thanks - knew it had to be a simple one, but couldn't find the answer anywhere. You were fast!

Answer (score 6):

Use `sudo` (so you have full priveleges) to run the `chmod` (ie "change mode" or "change permissions") command.

```
sudo chmod g-s thefilename
```

The argument `g-s` says "remove the `s` flag from the `group` permissions block". `s` stands for `sticky`, but it's meaning these days is a bit different and varies depending on whether it's on a file or directory.

To learn more, see the [chmod manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).

Answer (score 1):

`chmod g-s <target>` should be enough.